# CSS issue with the site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I can't seem to pinpoint the issue with menu under the title being pushed down when there are two select boxes on the right under the product.

[site urls removed]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding and/or seeing the behavior you're describing. Is this a browser specific issue?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854636/css-margin-issue-in-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space is because you have second dropdown - 'size' - in the right-hand panel.

The easy solution is to remove this dropdown, but the bigger problem is your inflexible CSS - you need to rewrite this.

Have a look at floating the columns of content left and right with the heading above both of them.  Avoiding relying on margins like the `margin-top: -490px;` definition on your `product-collateral` div as these will break when the content changes - as you've just seen..

Comment: Yea I'm thinking to add id to that div class then reduce margin-top just for that. What do you think?

Comment: That would fix it, but in an inflexible short-term way. If that is your easiest solution it would be better to add a class such as 'two-dropdown-items' which you could then reuse on other pages with two dropdowns.

Comment: That is what I am doing but where can I find html files in magento?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Magento.

Answer (score 0):

yea I have to agree the layout of the code isn't really helping your situation.. for example the heading being within the column that needs to be floated right - but the heading needs to be left. Maybe even if you could just remove the heading from that part and wrap the left and right columns in their own divs? Reckon it'll be a little hacky with positioning otherwise?